# How to build web applications that have a look&feel like Google+?

Tags: user-interface, dojo, web, extjs, google-plus

For ages, our company uses Dojo as the interface library of choice. The applications created have a very desktop-like look & feel and are very suitable for business areas and banking.

However, I see a trend towards user interfaces that are more like Google+:

- page-based instead of internal scrolling
- not many modal popup windows but rather edit-in-place and drop-out things
- loading additional list items via scrolling to the bottom of the page

all that kind of user interaction. Basically, a light and more web-centric usability approach.

Unfortunatelly, I don't know of an library that really helps in building such interfaces - I know jQuery UI, Sencha, Cappucino, Sproutcore and the like, but they do not quite fit.

Does anybody know of some new ui component library for sites like Google+?

Comment: Dojo apps have desktop look and feel if you use layout containers... but I can't see a reason why all of this couldn't be achieved by using dojo... it has edit-in-place out of the box, and all the base libraries to do the other things you require...

Comment: Yes Philippe, basically you are right - but Dojo has a strong focus on the full-blown component model. If we do not find anything else, I guess we will use Dojo - but maybe a slimmer alternative has emerged...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of the interface patterns used in Google+ are in [Google Closure Library](http://code.google.com/closure/library/).

Comment: is Google Closure Library related to GWT?

Comment: No. Not directly. I'm sure the can be used together though.

Comment: Let's hope it won't be slashed as Google Gears

Comment: Gears has mostly been replaced with HTML5 APIs. Dart could conceivably make GWT less used, it will take years and it will require Java developers to learn a new language.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Are there any Google Closure Demo Applications? All I could finde were the usual toolbar demos in the Closure API Docs...

Comment: I assume there must be some demo apps but you might have to Google for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following book about Google closure : [Closure: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920001416.do) for reference.